# create event in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create an event to back up my database every Friday at midnight?

```
  CREATE EVENT baseballbackup
  ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 DAY
  STARTS (TIMESTAMP (CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  DO
  DELETE FROM baseball;
```

I am pretty sure the code posted is wrong. I am not sure what is the right syntax.

Comment: Do you mean creating sql server job?

Comment: Pretty sure? Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is :

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` 
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE] 
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
DO BEGIN
    -- event body
END;
```

Example :

```
CREATE 
    EVENT `baseballbackup` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2011-07-24 00:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM baseball WHERE deleted = 1; // or whatever you want
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve what you want for FRIDAY??

```
  CREATE EVENT baseballbackup
  ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
  STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 4 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND
  DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM baseball;
  END;
```